# Image not hyperlinked

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, icons

Currently my icons for my social media page isn't hyperlinked and I'm not sure why. I have it surrounded by the href  and for some reason it's not working. Could someone help me out there?

HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
 html{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left:0;
 overflow: hidden;
 }
 .background{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: -1000;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 }
 #background-video{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 }
 .content{
 position: absolute; 
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;
 }
 .content h1{
 font-family:Comic Sans MS,  sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 200px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #ffffff;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
 }
 .content h3{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 24px;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 color: #ffffff;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
 }
 img {
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 }
 .social-media-icons{
 z-index: 1000;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 padding-top: 35%;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="background" class="background">
  <video id="background-video"autoplay muted loop>
   <source src="background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
 <h1>A-T</h1>
 <h3>ONLINE PORTFOLIO DESIGNED BY </h3>
 </div>
 <div class="social-media-icons">
  <a target="_blank"  href=""><img class="facebook" src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
  <a target="_blank"  href=""><img class="twitter" src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
  <a target="_blank"  href=""><img class="LinkedIn" src="linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
  <a target="_blank"  href=""><img src="googleplus.png" alt="Google Plus" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
  <a href=""><img src="email.png" alt="Email" width="40px" height="40px"></a> 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above html code has the social media icons with  surrounding it. Is this because of the z-index? That's the only thing I can assume at this point in time.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:

Your content height is set to min-height:100%; This is causing the content div to cover your social media divs.

In order to make they clickable you have done the right thing by adding a z-index, however, z-index won't work when there is no positioning. If you set the position to relative they'll appear how to want. And you also need a destination in the href tags.

```
.social-media-icons{
   position:relative;
   z-index: 1000;
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
   padding-top: 35%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a destination inside **href** for each a tag.

```
<a target="_blank"  href="https://www.facebook.com"><img class="facebook" src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
```

Comment: I've done that and it still doesn't work for me at least.